# Create An Object from JSON Response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a response in JSON format form a PHP file through an AJAX call.

```
console.log(data["json"]);

[{"value":"23","label":"Assorted Juices"},{"value":"24","label":"Water"},{"value":"25","label":"Beers"},{"value":"26","label":"Carbonated Drinks"},{"value":"27","label":"Instant Beverages "},{"value":"28","label":"Energy Drinks"}]
```

I was able to loop through the JSON

```
var subCategory = data["json"];
//console.log(subCategory);
var obj = $.parseJSON(subCategory);
$.each(obj, function() {
$label = this['label'];
$value = this['value'];
});
```

I need a build an Object like below in javascript. How can i adjust the above loop to generate an object like this.

```
var data = [
    { label: 'Water', value: '24' },
    { label: 'Energy Drinks', value: '28' },
]
```

Comment: Can you amend the PHP code at all? Your data is already in the format you need, you just need to change the `id` key to be named `value`, and `name` to be `label` instead.

Comment: id and name are the database fields, please see above php code.

Comment: and... why can't you rename the fields within the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an object and pushing it ao an array can do the job.

```
var subCategory = data["json"];
//console.log(subCategory);
var obj = $.parseJSON(subCategory);
var data3 = [];
var counter = 0;
$.each(obj, function() {

$label = this['label'];
$value = this['value'];
var obj2 = { 
       label: $label,
       value: $value
   };
   data3.push(obj2);
});
```